# Teste Unitário Karma para Método Typescript/Angular

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular

Estou com dificuldades para testar um método de select, esse é o método:

```
select(task): any {
    (document.getElementById(task) as HTMLInputElement).select();
};
```

Ele é chamado pelo html, nessa parte aqui:

```
<button id="button-edit" mat-icon-button aria-label="Alterar" *ngIf="!row.canEdit" (click)="select(row.name)" (click)="checkEdit(row)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
```

O meu teste está assim por enquanto:

```
it('should select a task', () => {
    const getElementById = spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
    component.select(task[0].name);
    expect(getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Obtenho a seguinte exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('should select a task', () => {
    const obj ={
    select: function()=>{}
    }
    const getElementById = spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue(obj);

   const select = spyOn(obj, 'select');
   component.select(task[0].name);
   expect(getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect(select).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Deu certo, muitíssimo obrigado!